# How can I browse a network drive I have read-write access to in read-only mode?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shared-folders

I am concerned about accidentally deleting files on a Windows file share that I often need to access to retrieve files from. My permissions on the file share are "read-write", meaning I can update/delete files, which I occasionally need to do; but for safety and to avoid accidental deletion, I am looking for a way to browse/read the files that does not let me delete files in that particular access mode.

I don't want to change my permission on the share to "read only". So what would be a software solution in Windows 10 for just browsing the network share, besides making a copy of the files on my local system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could right click the share you wish to access as read only
select Map network drive

it will assign a drive letter to the shared folder example: (Z:)

now using Firefox you can go to the url file:///z:/

this will open the shared folder in a read-only state within Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of it! Actually one does not even need to map the network drive